# Spark RDD: set difference

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
val data: RDD [(String, Array[Int])] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("100",Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), ("1000",Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
))

val codes = sc.parallelize(Seq(2, 3, 12, 13))

val result = data.map {case (id,values) => (id, values.diff(codes))}
```

I would like to get the result as:

```
val result: Array[(String, Array[Int])] = Array(
  ("100", Array(1, 4, 5)), ("1000", Array(10, 11, 14))
)
```

However, when I do the set difference, I get type mismatch error.

Comment: Your code is missing something...what is `dummy_data_sorted`?

Comment: Sorry updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply operation on a local data structure there is no reason to parallelize `codes`. Just `mapValues` like this:

```
val codes = Seq(2, 3, 12, 13)
val result = data.mapValues(_.diff(codes))
```

If codes won't fit into memory you'll have to do something slightly more complicated:

```
// Add dummy values to codes
val codes = sc.parallelize(Seq(2, 3, 12, 13)).map((_, null))

data
  .flatMapValues(x => x)  // Flatten values (k, vs) => (k, v)
  .map(_.swap) // Swap order => (v, k)
  .subtractByKey(codes) // Difference
  .map(_.swap) // Swap order => (k, v)
  .groupByKey  // Group => (k, vs)
```

Comment: I would also make `codes` a broadcast variable in your first example. Your second example I think is not more efficient than a `groupByKey`, `join`, etc, which seem more intuitive when used.

Comment: @RaduIonescu If `code` is relatively large then sure. If it is small like in the example it is not worth all the fuss IMHO. Regarding your second remark. Could you provide some example?

Comment: `data.flatMapValues(x => x) .map(_.swap).leftOuterJoin(codes).map(...)` or  `data.flatMapValues(x => x) .map(_.swap).groupByKey().filter(...).map()`. The groupByKey may seem to output more tuples, but because of the DAG scheduler the filter and map operations will be performed on a tuple base and you end up with the same output.